# How can I avoid a language change in liferay to trigger the last actionReques

Tags: localization, liferay, portlet

When changing languages from the language portlet, the user is redirected to the last URL. If the URL corresponds to an actionRequest, that action is triggered a second time.

I tried with the following simple code, with the classic theme, in liferay 6.1 GA2

view.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL name="myProcessAction" var="myProcessActionURL" />
<a href="<%= myProcessActionURL %>">my process action</a>
<form action="<%= myProcessActionURL %>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

testportlet.java:

```
public class TestPortlet extends MVCPortlet {
    public void myProcessAction(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        _log.info("processing action");
    }
    private static Log _log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog("TestPortlet");
}
```

I add my test portlet to a new page, as well as the language portlet.

Submit the form -> log shows "processing action"
switch languages -> log shows "processing action" again !

Best regards,
Alain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify where the page is redirected by including a "redirect" parameter. For example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<portlet:namespace />redirect" value="/" />
```

The `MVCPortlet` class will automatically see this parameter and redirect to it if the request is successful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, rp. I unfortunately can't upvote it as I don't yet have enough reputation...